# How to cite sourcecode from an svn repository

Tags: bibtex, sourcecode

As part of my thesis I read some sourcecode. Unfortunately this sourcecode is only available as an svn repository. How do I write a reference to it? The shortest way I found of accessing it is:

```
svn checkout -r187 http://seccompsandbox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ seccompsandbox-read-only
```

How do i write a reference to such sourcecode?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

A possibility would be

```
@misc{key,
  title = {http://seccompsandbox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/},
  howpublished = {svn checkout -r187},
}
```

If you consider `biblatex` it has an `@online` entry type with support for `version`

```
@online{key,
  url = {http://seccompsandbox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk},
  version = {svn checkout -r187},
}
```